# Delegate loads the Alert Form but I can't use any of the components.. its stuck

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

The problem is below. Here's my code...

```
// Contents of Form1.cs
// Usual includes
namespace ProcessMonitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Boolean getStatus()
        {
            // Returns true if the system is active
            if (label1.Text.Equals("Active"))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(getStatus())
            {
                label1.Text = "Not Active";
                button1.Text = "Activate";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Active";
                button1.Text = "Deactivate";
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Monitor mon = new Monitor(this);
            mon.Run();
        }

    }
}

// Contents of Monitor.cs
// Usual includes
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProcessMonitor
{
    class Monitor
    {
        Form1 parent;
        private void ShowAlert(Alert al)
        {
            al.Show();
        }
        public Monitor(Form1 parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void InvokeMethod()
        {
            //This function will be on main thread if called by Control.Invoke/Control.BeginInvoke
            Alert frm = new Alert(this.parent);
            frm.Show();
        }

        // This method that will be called when the thread is started
        public void Run()
        {
            var query = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
              "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\");
            while (true)
            {
                using (var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query))
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject mo = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();a
                    //MessageBox.Show("Created process: " + ((ManagementBaseObject)mo["TargetInstance"])["Name"] + ",Path: " + ((ManagementBaseObject)mo["TargetInstance"])["ExecutablePath"]);
                    ManagementBaseObject o = (ManagementBaseObject)mo["TargetInstance"];
                    String str = "";
                    foreach (PropertyData s in o.Properties)
                    {
                        str += s.Name + ":" + s.Value + "\n";
                    }
                    this.parent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(InvokeMethod), null); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alert.cs is just a blank form with a label that says “new process has started”. I intend to display the name of the process and location, pid, etc. by passing it to this alert form via the Thread (i.e. class Monitor). I have deliberately made the thread load in form_load so that I can resolve this error first. Adding it as a thread properly after the main form loads fully is a later task. I need to fix this first..

The delegate creates the Alert form but I can’t click on it, its just stuck. Need help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop in `Run` is blocking the UI thread.

> by passing it to this alert form via the Thread

You never actually create a new thread or task here - you just run code which executes in the UI thread, and causes an infinite loop.  This will prevent the main form, as well as your `Alert` form, from ever displaying messages.

You need to push this into a background thread in order for it to work, ie:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            Monitor mon = new Monitor(this);
            mon.Run();
        });
    }
```